# Fiber product of nilmanifolds

Tags: principal-bundles, homogeneous-spaces, pullback

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be nilmanifolds. We can see them as total spaces of torus bundles $\pi_i:M_i \to B_i\ \ i=1,2$. Suppose that $B_1=B_2$ and that the fibers are torus of the same dimension and consider the fiber product $M_1 \times_B M_2$ (which I believe is the same thing as the pullback bundles $\pi_1^*M_2$ and $\pi_2^*M_1$).

Then $M_1\times_B M_2$ is also a torus bundle over $B$. But is it a nilmanifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

We can instead view $M_1\times_B M_2$ as a principal torus bundle over $M_1$, as in the following pullback diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
{T}_2 & = & T_2 \newline
\downarrow & & \downarrow \newline
M_1\times_B M_2 & \to & M_2 \newline
\downarrow & & \downarrow \newline
M_1 & \to & B
\end{array}
$$
Since a (compact) nilmanifold is nothing but an iterated principal torus bundle, and $M_1$ is a nilmanifold, it follows by induction that $M_1\times_B M_2$ is a nilmanifold.